# Improper Integral with trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Determine if the following integral converges: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^3+4x}dx.$$

So far I've thought about using the comparison test but I'm not sure how to implement it. My first thought would be that $\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+4x}\leq \frac{1}{x(x^2+4)}$ but I am stuck here. Any help with this would be great. Thank you!

Comment: The divergence of this integral is due to the singularity at $0$.

Comment: Note that the integrand is an odd function.

Comment: The integral is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does
$$
\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{1/2}{x^3+x}\,dx
$$
converge?

Since $\cos x\ge 1/2$ for $0\le x\le \pi/3$, what can you say?

Comment: Well this integral diverges so my integral will diverge by the comparison test. Correct?

Comment: @user23793 Yes.